# Some vertex groups on the armature have their location offset

Tags: rigging, armature, vertex-groups

I am relatively new to blender. So this is my first time rigging with vertex groups. To my understanding, I have done everything properly when rigging my vertex groups to my armature: unparent all the meshes, join the meshes, match the name of the vertex groups to the bone names. So after I add the armature modifier to the mesh and select my armature as the object, some of the vertex groups are offset.

[image]

The weird thing is, the vertex groups are in the correct position in edit mode but not in object mode.

[image]

The animation works fine except for the few vertex groups that have the offset.

Comment: Hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/d5c50efe863049aaa822702afa563dff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it answers your questions:

In *Edit* mode you should align the bones with the lamp arms:

[image]

Also, stick the IK target head to the tail of the IK bone, otherwise, as soon as you switch to *Pose* mode, your IK will move away from its current position to stick to its target:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I cannot express my appreciation enough! I have been stuck on this problem for so long, and it is a relief finally having a solution! Thank you!